# Solve $z^{i+1}=4 $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

I know it must be pretty easy but i just can't get it. I try to use the fact that $$e^{clogz}=z^c$$ $c \in C$ but still i can't. Can you write all of the steps in order to understand what i'm missing in solving equations of this type.

I need to solve $$z^{1+i}=4$$

Comment: How do you define $\log z$ for $z$ complex in the first formula in your post?

Comment: $w=log|z|+ i(argz+2kp)$   where $ w=e^z$

Comment: You are near the solution: the next step is $4=e^{\log 4}$. Now compare the two sides.

Comment: "w=log|z|+i(argz+2kp) where w=ez" This (once one got rid of the typos) seems to be a set, not a number (provided we know how $\arg z$ is defined), hence $z^c$ is a set of complex numbers; how could it be equal to $4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  z^{1+i} &= 4 \\
  (1+i) \log z &= \ln 4+2n\pi i \\
  \log z &= \frac{\ln 4+2n\pi i}{1+i} \\
         &= \frac{(\ln 4+2n\pi i)(1-i)}{2} \\
         &= \left( \ln 2+n\pi \right)+i(n\pi-\ln 2) \\
  z &= 2e^{n\pi} \operatorname{cis} (n\pi-\ln 2)
\end{align*}

where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Lovely stuff +1

Comment: very nice :) !!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $4=\exp( \log(4)+2\pi i k)$ with $k\in {\Bbb Z}$ and find the solutions to
$$(1+i)\log z = \log(4)+2\pi i k$$

Answer (score 1):

Generalize the problem, when $\text{q}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\text{a}\in\mathbb{R}^+$, solve $\text{z}$:

$$\text{z}^{\text{q}}=\text{a}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Take the natural logarithm of both sides and bring the power out in front:

---

$$\text{q}\ln(\text{z})=\ln(\text{a})+2\pi ki\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Divide both sides by $\text{q}$:

---

$$\ln(\text{z})=\frac{\ln(\text{a})+2\pi ki}{\text{q}}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Cancel logarithms by taking exp of both sides:

---

$$\text{z}=\exp\left[\frac{\ln(\text{a})+2\pi ki}{\text{q}}\right]$$